# Objective-c return method returning NSMutableArray instead of declared NSArray return type

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nsarray, return-type

If I want to return an immutable array like this `+ (NSArray *)ids` but inside this method I'm declaring a `NSMutableArray` because I want to sort it using `-sortUsingSelector:`.

Returning this method works perfect.

- But is it "okay" to write code that declares that the return method should be one type and the actually type is another?
- Does this work because `NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray`?
- Is the actual return value an `NSArray` or an `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: In any language, the actual return type of a function may be a subtype of the declared return type as a consequence of the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> (…) is it "okay" to write code that declares that the return method should be one type and the actualy type is another?

Yes, it is provided the types are compatible; see the next paragraph. In fact, there are some cases in Cocoa (notably class clusters) that do that as well.

> Does this work because NSMutableArray is a subclass of NSArray?

Exactly. Since `NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray`, it inherits all its methods and declared properties, so it publicly behaves like `NSArray`. This is called the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

> Is the actual return value a NSArray or a NSMutableArray?

The return value is whatever you’re returning. Since you’re returning an `NSMutableArray`, it’s an `NSMutableArray`. From the caller perspective, it is an object that can be used like an `NSArray`.

Comment: Returning a mutable array from a method typed as returning an `NSArray *` is OK, but mutating the array you get from a method typed as returning an `NSArray *`is not OK. If the method's declaration doesn't explicitly say it returns a mutable array, you, the caller, should never assume it returns a mutable array. Even doing this inside your own application means you are making your own code that much more fragile. If the class is telling its own array to sort itself, the method should be an accessor explicitly returning mutable. Any other class should make its own mutable copy.

Comment: @Peter Hosey: +1.  The Apple docs explicitly ban treating an object as mutable if the API advertises it as immutable *even if you test it first and find that it is mutable*.

Comment: @Jer And [testing for mutability is not as simple as it might initially seem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1788690/557219).

Answer (score 2):

- Whether it's "okay" or not is a difficult question. If it's a small project and only you use the code, it might be allright. However, if you rely on nothing being able to change the "`NSArray`" returned, it's not ok. (See the last point)
- Yes.
- It's an `NSMutableArray`. A simple cast will let you change the values in it.

If you actually want to a return an immutable object, do the following:

```
  NSArray* immutableArray = [[mutableArray copy] autorelease];
  return immutableArray;
```

Comment: Don't forget to autorelease it, when not running under GC or ARC.