# CFArrayRef class use iskindofclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

In Following Code I check array with `isKindOfClass`, But When I check with if it will true for both condition :

```
 NSString *values[] = {@"hello", @"world"};
    CFArrayRef arrayRef = CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (void *)values, (CFIndex)2, NULL);
    NSArray *array = (__bridge  NSArray *)arrayRef;
    if ([array isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
        NSLog(@"array is mutableArray");
    }
    if ([array isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        NSLog(@"array is immutabelArray");
}
```

result:

```
2016-09-16 10:00:32.873 TestArray[12246:198137] array is mutableArray
2016-09-16 10:00:32.874 TestArray[12246:198137] array is immutabelArray
```

The results make me confused
array is immutable,but why print array is mutable.

Comment: Add another log: `NSLog(@"array is a %@", [array class]);`.

Comment: You should also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788690/objective-c-how-to-check-if-variable-is-nsarray-or-nsmutablearray

Answer (score 0):

If you read Apple document, you will see
`@interface NSMutableArray<ObjectType> : NSArray<ObjectType>`
So if your object is kind of NSMutableArray, it definitely is kind of NSArray.
You should check by `NSLog(@"array class %@", [array class]);`

Comment: my question is a NSArray object that  It is determined as a NSMutableArray